# JavaScript: getComputedStyle inconsistent return value between browsers

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the value of the CSS left attribute like so...
`window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.test'), ':after').getPropertyValue('left');`

The problem is that this returns a pixel value in Chrome, but a percentage in FireFox. Is there any way to get it to force it to always return a pixel value?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r8mynvL4/2/

HTML:

`<div class="test">This is a test.</div>`

CSS:

```
.test {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

.test:after {
  content: '*';
  bottom: -10%;
  left: 95%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

JS:

```
var leftValue = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.test'), ':after').getPropertyValue('left');

console.log(leftValue);
```

Comment: Ah there is already one : https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=925694#comment_tag_7

Comment: `getComputedStyle should return the computed value, serialized in px` - that is not the case for all attributes - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle#Notes

Comment: @Kaiido - that bug is about `width` and `height` - nothing to do with `left`

Comment: @jaromandaX i only fast read it but it sounded like a bug on not returning computed values but rather authored ones. which would apply to any property

Comment: see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/computed_value and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/used_value and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resolved_value as well as the documentation for getComputedStyle - see if you can determine which browser is "correct" - because, I can't!!!

Comment: @JaromandaX It's a working draft, so technically neither browser is "correct". However, Gecko is actually following the definition in the specification as it stands right now.

Comment: Specifically: `if specified as a '<length>', the corresponding absolute length; if specified as a '<percentage>', the specified value; otherwise, auto. ` - Computed value of the `left` [property definition](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-position-3/#propdef-left).

Comment: @Kaiido That's not how the specs typically work (unfortunately) - each one references which specification it uses to define e.g. its properties. The spec I quoted is the one which also applies to pseudo-elements. The older spec likely defines it differently and applies to non-pseudo-elements only (because pseudo's didn't exist).

Comment: (Example of that: [here's one of the specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-pseudo-4/#generated-content) defining ::after and ::before - notice that they explicitly declare _CSS3_)

Comment: @LukeBriggs, you are probably right since `pc` values are correctly converted to `px`. But IMM if they're gonna follow a version of the specs, they should apply it entirely, not just at some parts. Still sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: @Kaiido the classic issue is actually Gecko following the specifications _too_ closely - that can introduce strange compatibility issues when other browser vendors don't do that. Generally though the inconsistency of the overall API will result in the specs being revised.

Comment: @LukeBriggs, You should probably post an answer with all this, since it does provide some good info on what is going on. Note that [the workaround](http://jsfiddle.net/3FecG/3/) posted by [e.generalov](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=925694#c7) in linked bug report should do [for OP too](http://jsfiddle.net/uqjqbzbp/).

Answer (score 4):

To directly answer the question, yes, try this method by e.generalov as described originally in a [bugzilla report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=925694#c7):

```
function getComputedStylePropertyValue(who, pseudo, propName) {
    var dv = who.ownerDocument.defaultView,
        cStyle = dv.getComputedStyle(who, pseudo),
        tmpNode = null, propVal;

    if (pseudo) {
        var css = cStyle.cssText;
        if (!css) { // it is an empty string. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=137687 
            var sty = [];
            for (var key in cStyle) {
                if (cStyle.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    sty.push(cStyle[key] + ':' + cStyle.getPropertyValue(cStyle[key]));
                }
            }
            css = sty.join(';');
        }
        tmpNode = document.createElement('dummy');
        tmpNode.style.cssText = css;
        if (pseudo === '::before' && who.firstChild) {
            who.insertBefore(tmpNode, who.firstChild);
        } else { // ::before in case of empty element or ::after
            who.appendChild(tmpNode);
        }
        cStyle = dv.getComputedStyle(tmpNode, null);
    }

    propVal = cStyle.getPropertyValue(propName);

    if (tmpNode) {
        tmpNode.parentNode.removeChild(tmpNode);
    }
    return propVal;
}
```

[Here it is as a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uqjqbzbp/).

## Which browser is correct?

It might surprise you that it's actually **Gecko (Firefox)** which *appears* to be correctly implementing the specification as it stands right now. *(I say appears, because there may of course still be bugs in some parts of it)*. The quick summary is [this part of the 'left' property definition](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-position-3/#propdef-left):

> Otherwise: if specified as a '<length>', the corresponding absolute length; if specified as a '<percentage>', the specified value; otherwise, auto.

*Definition of the computed value - left property. "Otherwise" is applying because of the position:absolute declaration.*

So, why doesn't Chrome do that? It seems fairly clear, right? Well, if you're interested in finding out how this standard became relatively inconsistent, read on!

## The evolution of CSS - A battle of backwards compatibility vs. consistency

Firstly, newer user agents like Chrome don't need to bother much with backwards compatibility and can essentially ignore older and more obscure parts of the CSS specifications.

It's of course a different story for Gecko and the specifications themselves. CSS is *versionless* - your website doesn't declare which version of CSS it's using, for example. Instead, CSS modules organically build on top of *each other* and *must* be backwards compatible.

Meanwhile, Chrome favours consistency. It occasionally strays quite far from the strict definitions of the specifications with the reasoning being to push the web forward. The typical result is the specification gets updated to reflect anything that turned out well.

## But Firefox is inconsistent with itself? Surely it's a bug?

[This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r8mynvL4/3/) shows that non-pseudo elements do actually return px values. In short, this is attributed to the way in which CSS modules reference each other. It's the strict adherence to this referencing scheme that makes Firefox the *de facto* reference implementation from the W3C's point of view.

So, for example, the definition of [getComputedStyle](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-CSSview-getComputedStyle) explicitly references CSS level 2:

> This method is used to get the computed style **as it is defined in [CSS2]**.

If we then proceed to take a look at the definition of a computed value as it is [defined in there](https://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-CSS2-19980512/cascade.html#computed-value) then we see that it once was defined in pixels:

> percentages must be multiplied by a reference value (each property defines which value that is)

Meanwhile, pseudo-elements like ::before and ::after explicitly reference CSS3; they use the CSS3 description of `left` which [now defines it differently](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-position-3/#propdef-left).

Keep in mind that this specification *is a working draft* - it's not a requirement for browsers to follow it (but Firefox is doing so). Chrome on the other hand is pushing the consistency line - i.e. the whole API always only returns those *used values*.

Comment: This works wonderfully for getting a pixel value in Firefox, but I am still getting a percentage in Safari...is there any way to modify the function you provided so that it will always return a pixel, regardless of browser?

Comment: @m-use It sounds like non-psuedo elements return % in Safari: If that's the case then you'd be out of luck other than resolving the % unit for yourself. E.g. If `cStyle.contains('%')` then parse out the number and multiply it by the reference value. Figuring out the reference value is tricky: It depends on axis (i.e. `margin-top:50%` is on Y, `margin-left:50%` is on X) and on the what the property is relative to (e.g. background-size is relative to "this", whereas most are relative to the "parent" inner width/ inner height). The "parent" also depends on how the element is positioned too!

Comment: (For example, `position:fixed;` means `top:50%` is typically 50% of the viewport, but it can also be 50% of the "nearest transformed ancestor")